# org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not determine type of dynamic entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I am a beginner in Hibernate and I have the below code in one of my projects:

```
ShortHand o = new ShortHand();
    Session sess = noprobs.getSessionFactory().openSession();


                    sess.getTransaction().setTimeout(noprobs.xActionTimeout);
                tx = sess.beginTransaction();
                sess.save(o);
```

For which I get the below error:

**ERROR:**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not determine type of dynamic entity
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.guessEntityName(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at cool.wxhy.tms.xyz.ABCD.persistInDb(ABCD.java:235)
    at cool.wxhy.tms.xyz.ABCD.subscribeToAmps(ABCD.java:144)
    at cool.wxhy.tms.xyz.ABCD.hot(ABCD.java:102)
    at cool.wxhy.service.impl.wxhyBase.start(wxhyBase.java:250)
    at cool.wxhy.service.api.hello.startAllServices(hello.java:211)
    at cool.wxhy.service.impl.heyhi.main(heyhi.java:43)
```

I am using the `HIbernate 3.2.6 jar`

I am using the xml config for the HIbernate and not the annotations one. Can someone please help on the issue.

**Hibernate Mapping file:**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="bofa.pioneer.tms.objects">
    <class name="ShortHand" table="ShortHand">
      <id name="key" column="id" unsaved-value="null" type="string" >
        <generator class="assigned" />
      </id>

        <property name="animal" column="animal" type="string"/>
        <property name="dog" column="dog" type="string"/>
```

**Entity**

```
public class ShortHand extends LongHand {
 //getters and setters are present in the parent LongHand
 }
```

Comment: Can you add your entity and configuration file?

Comment: And LongHand is obviously configured as @MappedSuperclass right?:>

Comment: I dont have annotations in my project. I am using xml

Comment: I assume it must be configured in similar manner i think.

Comment: @Antoniossss parent and subclass both have separate mapping files and separate tables